# List of U.S. trucking companies with additional info

Tags: usa, data.gov, transportation, companies

I'm looking for data set of trucking companies in de U.S. Specifically:

- Name
- Phone number
- DOT#
- MC#
- etc...

Answer (score 1):

Two unofficial sources for at least some of the information you're looking for: this seems to be a pretty long list of contact info of trucking companies: http://www.truckdrivercentral.com/truckingcompanies.html and here's one linking to a lot of websites: http://www.thetruckersplace.com/companies2.aspx

If you're okay with spending some money, this service looks like it might be able to help you out: https://www.tdsource.com/